# Jquery function works just once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've a form and button, which after clicked should display a message.  The problem is that now  the message is shown just once for the first click. Could anybody explain me what am I doin wrong?

JQUERY:

```
function post_comment(id) {
    x = "#c" + id;
    $(x).click(function () {
        $('.login_modal_message').fadeIn(500);
        $('body').append('<div id="overlay"></div>');
        $('#overlay').fadeIn(300);
        return false;

        $('#overlay, .close').live('click', function () {
            $('#overlay , .login_modal_message').fadeOut(300, function () {
                $('#overlay').remove();
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
};
```

HTML:

```
 <form id="c408" method="post">
     <textarea class="comment_input" name="comment" placeholder="Write your comment here..."> 
     <input id="post_id" hidden="hidden" value="408" name="post_id">
     <button class="comment_button" onclick="post_comment(408)">Send</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: what version of jQuery are you using? the preferred method of `live` is now `$('#overlay').on('.close', 'click', function () {`

Comment: Which button doesn't work?  Is it when you submit a comment or when you delete one?

Comment: @Neil - .on accepts event first, then optional selector. your example should be `$('#overlay').on('click', '.close', function () {`

Comment: Side note, you're not closing your textarea properly.

Comment: I think you are creating more than one `<div id="overlay"></div>` so you lose the reference on second time...

Comment: Your first `return false;` will stop the rest of your function from executing every time.

Comment: @user1477388 There is no delete button.

Answer (score 0):

How do you trigger this? Because you are using a function for something an eventhandler could do

```
$('.openName').click(function(event) {
    $('.login_modal_message').fadeIn(500);
    $('body').append('<div id="overlay"></div>');
    $('#overlay').fadeIn(300); 
    //return false;// Never return false unless you know what you are doing:
    event.preventDefault()
});

$('#overlay, .close').live('click', function(event) { 
    $('#overlay , .login_modal_message').fadeOut(300 , function() {
        $('#overlay').remove();
    }); 
    //return false;// Never return false unless you know what you are doing:
    event.preventDefault()
});
```

---

The order of fadeins is a bit weird, I cant figure out wether this is what you want. First the message comes, than fade a background?

Answer (score 0):

You should bind the event handler to the form itself and catch the submit. Like so:

**UPDATE with full jQuery**

```
function post_comment(id) {
  x = "#c" + id;

  $(x).submit(function() {
    $('#overlay').fadeIn(300);

    return false;
  });
}

$('#close-modal').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  $('#overlay').fadeOut();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="c408" method="post">
  <textarea class="comment_input" name="comment" placeholder="Write your comment here..."></textarea>
  <input id="post_id" hidden="hidden" value="408" name="post_id" />
  <button class="comment_button" onclick="post_comment(408)">Send</button>
</form>

<div class='overlay' id='overlay'>
<div class='login_modal_message' id='login_modal_message'>
  <p>Message</p>
  <a href='#' id="close-modal">Close modal</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
  bottom: 0;
  display: none;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.login_modal_message {
  background: white;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100px;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 200px;
}
```

**Update: Added [Codepen sketch.](http://cdpn.io/jHJtb)**

Comment: I'll put up a full sketch.